# Fazer consulta e baixar NFe

Tags: python, nfe

Estou querendo fazer um programa para consultar e baixar de NF-e e gostaria de saber quais o Web Services eu conectaria para conseguir fazer meu aplicativo rodar.

Comment: Helio, eu fechei sua pergunta porque ela está longe de ser sobre programação ou desenvolvimento de sistemas. Como o Tony já lhe respondeu, basta acessar a lista no site da Receita. Porém, sinta-se à vontade para postar novas perguntas sobre assuntos técnicos específicos. Abraço!

Answer (score 2):

Depende do Estado (UF).
Dê uma olhada na lista atualizada no Site Oficial do Projeto NF-e:

http://www.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/portal/WebServices.aspx

Outra boa fonte de consulta é no site do Projeto UniNFe:

http://www.unimake.com.br/uninfe/

Comment: Tony, obrigado por responder vou dá uma olhada. Apesar que os webservices eu já tinha visto a lista no site oficial da fazenda, mas como sou meio cru ainda, não tinha vi os WS para consulta e tals. Mais tarde respondo. Vlw

Comment: Não é tão simples, dê uma olhada no código fonte do UniNFe, apesar de não ser na sua linguagem pode servir de referência.

Comment: Na verdade eu queria, Importar do Sefaz e Gerenciar todas as NFe de um CNPJ válido

Comment: Infelizmente, parece que este serviço ainda não está disponível. Já era para eles terem liberado um webservice que faça isto, já que o cliente tem o certificado para autenticar, e fazer o download das notas que lhe dizem respeito. Fica aqui a sugestão, caso algum desenvolvedor do governo esteja lendo isto.

Comment: Tony, veja isto: http://nasajon.com.br/solucoes/novo-produto/linha-nuvem-nf-arquivo Este pessoal faz isso já, só não sei como...rs

Comment: Pode ser que eles utilizem o método de abrir aquela página de download do XML e então programaticamente leiam o conteúdo. Consultar NF-e Completa http://www.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/portal/consulta.aspx?tipoConsulta=completa&tipoConteudo=XbSeqxE8pl8=

Comment: Entendo, meu amigo comprou esse serviços deles pagando 69,00 mês, sendo que ele fazer assim... ele entra com o certificado digital dai ele consegue fazer o download dos XMLs, lançados no dia, mês e ano.

Comment: Bem, se você descobrir a forma de fazer isto e quiser compartilhar conosco depois, pode voltar e colocar uma resposta.

Comment: Verdade. Tony eu descobri... realmente tem como fazer isso usando o servidor do RS. Porém ainda estou buscando fazer os scripts para acessar essas informações usando o Python. Obrigado. Quando tiver algo concreto vou postar aqui.

Comment: @Helio, Você achou a solução usando Python?

Comment: Não. Acabei desistindo depois de muitas tentativas.